# Problems sending info with ajax by post

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, post

I made a moderation script, voting up and down question and answers. Time ago the script worked, but when i came back to start coding in this project one more time, it doesn't work anymore.

The script was doing: when you click in a div called vote, or vote1 a link, it ask if it's up or down. If it's up, it loads url: "mod_up_vote.php" sending by post some info about the question you are voting on. It was ok. But not now. It doesn't load that page, because i was printing and inserting in database the $_POST variable and nothing was there.

What do you think is wrong here? Thanks.

```
   $(document).ready(function()
   {

   $(document).delegate('.vote, .vote1', '.vote2', 'click', function()
       {

   var id = $(this).attr("id");
   var name = $(this).attr("name");
   var dataString = 'id='+ id ;
   var parent = $(this);

   if(name=='mod_up')
   {

   $(this).fadeIn(200).html('<img src="dot.gif" align="absmiddle">');
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "mod_up_vote.php",
      dataType: "xml",
      data: dataString,
      cache: false,

      success: function(xml)
      {
   //$("#mod-pregunta").html(html);
   //$("#mod-respuesta").html(html);

   //parent.html(html);
    $(xml).find('pregunta').each(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var pregunta = $(this).find('preguntadato').text();
    var respuesta = $(this).find('respuestadato').text();
    var votoup = $(this).find('votoup').text();
    var votodown = $(this).find('votodown').text();
    var id_pregunta = $(this).find('id_pregunta').text();
    var id_respuesta = $(this).find('id_respuesta').text();
    $("#mod-pregunta").html(pregunta);
    $("#mod-respuesta").html(respuesta);
    //$(".vote").attr('id', $(this).find('id_pregunta').text());
    $(".vote1").html("<a href=\"modera\" title=\""+ id_pregunta + "-"+ id_respuesta + "-1\" class=\"vote1\" id=\""+ id_pregunta + "-"+ id_respuesta + "-1\" name=\"mod_up\">Aceptar</a>");
    $(".vote2").html("<a href=\"modera\" title=\""+ id_pregunta + "-"+ id_respuesta + "-2\" class=\"vote2\" id=\""+ id_pregunta + "-"+ id_respuesta + "-2\" name=\"mod_up\">Rechazar</a>");

    //$("span", this).html("(ID = '<b>" + this.id + "</b>')");
     });
     }  });

   }
 return false;
});
```

Comment: Are you sure that it's not loading the page? Have you checked that there's no errors in the PHP page?

Comment: In url: "mod_up_vote.php", i'm inserting into database a test value, and it doesn't save anything.

Comment: but are you sure that it's inserting it correctly? It sounds like it might be a problem with "mod_up_vote.php".

Comment: This is my link where it's call the function: <a href="modera" class="vote1" id="<?php echo $id_pregunta."-".$id_respuesta; ?>-1" name="mod_up">Aceptar</a> i changed to href=mod_up_vote.php and it display the blank page with array() and inserting the test value into database. The empty array is $_POST

Comment: you should post the code inside `mod_up_vote.php`

Comment: <?php

//session_start();
include("config.php");
include("Connections/preguntasidiotas1.php");
require('LoginSystem.class.php');
print_R($_POST);
 $post=$_POST;
 $query_prueba = "Insert into prueba values('asd')";
 mysql_query($query_prueba, $preguntasidiotas1) or die(mysql_error());

But i think it isn't the problem here. I linked directly to this page and it inserted the value.

Comment: I wrote alert (dataString); inside of <<if(name=='mod_up')>>
and I didn't got any alert. And i wrote it outside of the if and nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a problem with your JQuery. Why are you using [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) instead of [`click`](http://api.jquery.com/click/)? Also, your arguments to delegate appear to be incorrect. If you look at the documentation you'll see the function signature is:

```
$(elements).delegate(selector, events, data, handler);  // jQuery 1.4.3+
```

You are binding your function to an event called `'.vote2'`, which I can only assume does not exist.

Try using [`click`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) instead, there's no reason to use delegate as far as I can tell.

edit:

Try using `click` like so:

```
$('.vote, .vote1').click(function(){ /* your code here */ });
```

Comment: I'm using https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js But i'll see that. Because i need the function only work in href with class vote2, vote1... How should i do that?(using click) Thanks. +1 btw.

Comment: aW! Thanks! btw, i deleted the vote2. So it was selectors and after click. It worked now, It inserted the test value in the db! and the alert it's working too! And the moderation!! haha Thanks. I'll see if using click it works too, thanks.